# MVVM Best practice for Mobile App

Tags: swift, design-patterns, mobile, mvvm, language-agnostic

I have serious doubts on how in deep we have to use view model.

Let me explain with an example (in Swift, but language isn't important), simple view controller with a table view inside and a related view model.

```
class FooViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

     let viewModel = FooViewModel()

     @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
     }

    // MARK: - Table view delegates -

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return viewModel.heightForRow()
    }    
}

class FooViewModel {

    // MARK: - Table view management -

    func heightForRow() -> CGFloat {
        return 60.0
    }

}
```

Is a correct practice to delegate to the view model, for example, the height of each cell?
Generally, is ok delegate to view model UI "decision" on its aspect?

Answer (score 1):

My general rule for placing things in the view model is if I will test them or not. Since we don't test view controllers, if something needs to be tested, consider placing it in the view model. If the row height is calculated, I'd consider placing it in the view model so it can be tested.